# File not saving, or not

Tags: c++

I cannot seem to figure out why, during the while loop at the bottom,

```
std::cout << line;
```

does not print anything.

I believe that the test.txt file is not actually being written to because when I open test.txt in my folder, its empty. Any thoughts?

```
void Ticket::WriteTicket()
{
    std::string ticketInput;
    std::ofstream ticketFile("test.txt");

    ticketFile.open("test.txt");
    std::cout << "Please Enter Ticket Information: " << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, ticketInput);

    std::cout << ticketInput << std::endl; //does print out the line
    ticketFile << ticketInput;
    ticketFile.close();

    //here for testing only
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream ticketRead("test.txt");

    while(getline(ticketRead, line));
    {
        std::cout << "something here?: " << line; // there is nothing here when it outputs
    }
}
```

**EDIT (SOLUTION):**

After using some of the information that was given above, mainly from *Basile Starynkevitch* (I put this here because I cannot upvote yet), I was able to get the code to work!

I also did some research in my book and copied a similar program's style. Aka where to put what part of the code, and then the input worked. I continued on with the output and the key part was the `std::ifstream::in` in the opening of the file for output.

```
void Ticket::WriteTicket()
{
    std::string ticketInput;

    std::cout << "Please Enter Ticket Information: " << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, ticketInput);

    std::ofstream ticketFile("Ticket.txt");

    ticketFile << ticketInput << std::endl;

    ticketFile.close();

    //here for testing
    std::ifstream ticketRead;
    ticketRead.open("Ticket.txt", std::ifstream::in);
    std::string line;

    while(getline(ticketRead, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: Please compile with all warnings (e.g. `g++ -Wall`) and learn to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: You should either pass the filename to the constructor or use the open function, but not both.

Comment: Retired Ninja, I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: The `std::ofstream` constructor automatically opens the file for you, and the destructor automatically closes it.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realize I could do that. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[C++ I/O](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) is buffered. At least code

```
 std::cout << "something here?: " << line << std::flush;
```

but in your case

```
 std::cout << "something here?: " << line << std::endl;
```

would be better.

Also

```
 std::ofstream ticketFile("test.txt")
```

should probably be

```
 std::ofstream ticketFile("test.txt", std::ios_base::out);
```

I strongly suggest taking some hours to read more about [C++ libraries](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) before coding. Check every function or class that you are using. Of course, you also need to [std::flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) on `ticketFile`.

Comment: Hrmm I think the problem is the writing of the file because either way the test.txt file seems empty.

Comment: I am trying to do this to learn, it is a chapter project. Also I tried adding what you said `ofstream ticketFile("test.txt", std::ios_base::out);` It did not change anything

Comment: Doesn't close perform an implicit flush?

Answer (score 2):

You need to flush the output buffer.

```
ticketFile << ticketInput;
```

should be

```
ticketFile << ticketInput << std::endl;
```

[std::endl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) flushes the output buffer.See [std::flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) if you don't want the new line.

Comment: I tried doing this and I still see no text in test.txt if i open it, and it still doesn't output anything during the while statement.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code, made the above change and it worked. Check you haven't made any addition changes whilst trying to fix it. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the file need to be openned in write mode.
Try this
`std::ofstream ticketFile("test.txt","w");`

Comment: `std::ofstream ticketFile("test.txt", "w");`

does not compile :(

Comment: Then try "w+" instead.